# When does this self-modifying program for an accumulator architecture terminate?

Tags: cpu, computer-science, cpu-architecture, accumulator

I have this machine code for an accumulator architecture.
The architecture is eight-bit; the instruction encoding looks like
the real machine code is for instruction one for example is : 001 1 0001, 001 means LOAD, 1 tells us that is a value, and 001 is the decimal 1 so its LOAD #1

```
0---LOAD #1
1---STORE 15
2---LOAD #0
3---EQUAL #4
4---JUMP #6
5---HALT
6---LOAD 3
7---SUB #1
8---STORE 3
9---LOAD 15
10--ADD 15
11--STORE 15
12--JUMP #2
13-- 000 0 0000
14-- 000 0 0000
15-- 000 0 0000
```

I have to find what will be in memory cell 15 when the program stops.

But if you jump to instruction 2, this means that accumulator would have the value 0 which will never be equal to 4 and the program will just run as endless loop, right?

And what does the STORE 3 do, if memory cell 3 is empty? Does it mean that when a memory cell is empty its value is number 0?

I cannot proceed more without answering these two questions

Comment: The title of your question could use some *serious* improvement. There is pretty much zero information in the title that actually helps someone decide whether this is a question that interests them or not.

Comment: I changed it, but I cannot find the right title for this, the exact one

Comment: You need to explain what architecture this is for.

Comment: We just used an 8 bit Processor, so the real machine code is for instruction one for example is : 001 1 0001,  001 means LOAD, 1 tells us that is a value, and 001 is the decimal 1 so its LOAD #1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that this is for a n accumulator architecture, and I'm having to make a number of assumptions about that architecture.  You really need to describe more of how your CPU works to make this an answerable question.

Yes, at #3, the accumulator will always be 0.
And yes, if instruction #3 never changes, then 0 will never equal 4 and the program will loop for ever.

However, when you store to memory cell 3, I wthink that you end up replacing the instruction at cell 3 with what is in the accumulator now.
So, the interesting question is what happens when you subtract 1 from the instruction representation of `equal #4`.
That depends on yoru specific architecture, but my strong guess is that you get `equal #3` and store that in cell 3.

That should be enough for you to walk through and figure out when your loop terminates and what is in cell 15.

Comment: This is the architecture I am using, http://courses.cs.vt.edu/csonline/MachineArchitecture/Lessons/CPU/Lesson.html

Comment: And when you jump to instruction 2, the instruction 2 will set the accumulator to 0, and then instruction three compares "Is the number in accumulator the same as number 4", it will always do this job, which always has the same answer: NO, and the loop goes infinitely, it actually does not terminate (I think so), if the instruction 12 was "JUMP #3", this will make a complete sense

Comment: Ou I think now I understand you, the instruction "Equal #4" is in the cell 3 and subtract one from it, and then we load the cell 3 which is Equal #4 - #1 = Equal #3, and then Equal #3-#1 = Equal #2, then Equal #2-#1 = Equal #1 and in the end Equal #1 - #1 = Equal #0 and then the program terminates

Comment: Yes, exactly.  This program is self-modifying, which was very common for accumulator architectures.

Comment: If this answers ended up helping, please accept it.

Comment: Yep now it makes a complete sense, I was very confused, thank you very much, now I think I understand this architecture very good :)